# Where are stored the generated Spring dynamic proxies?

Tags: spring, storage, dynamic-proxy

Can anyone please tell me where dynamic proxies (the bytecode) generated by the Spring framework are **stored/held**?

On the filesystem? In memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location of the proxy class generated by Spring AOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520330/location-of-the-proxy-class-generated-by-spring-aop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in memory - there is no bytecode enhancement of the class, but essentially a wrapper is created which intercepts all method calls to the wrapped class and delegates the calls to an InvocationHandler .

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html